# Deny access to all PHP files using FilesMatch, but make an exception for one file

Tags: htaccess, apache, access-control

Currently, using htaccess I am denying access to any PHP file in a directory, but not the JS, PNG, CSS files in the same directory.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What if I want to make an exception for one file ("foobar.php" for example) however? Can I write multiple statements in a single htaccess? What is the order of execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I write multiple statements in a single htaccess?

Yes, you can. Multiple `<FilesMatch>` containers in the same *context* (ie. `.htaccess`) are merged in order. So, you can block all `.php` files and permit a specific `foobar.php` file - in that order.

For example:

```
# Block all ".php" files
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Permit a specific ".php" file
<FilesMatch "^foobar\.php$">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Alternatively, you can use a single `<FilesMatch>` container and use a *negative lookahead* in the regex to exclude the specific file:

```
# OR use a negative lookahead...
<FilesMatch "^(?!foobar\.php$).+\.php$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The *negative lookahead assertion* `(?!foobar\.php$)` ensures that the regex does not match `foobar.php`, whilst matching all other `.php` files.

Note that `Order`, `Deny`, `Allow` are strictly Apache 2.2 directives. If you are on Apache 2.4 then you should probably change this to `Require all denied` and `Require all granted` respectively (providing you have changed over to mod_authz_core throughout your system).

Note also that the `<FilesMatch>` container applies to the current directory and *all subdirectories*.